# box shadow is not working in compressed version of css in IE8?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, css

i have a image in which on hover i applied css of boxshadow. for IE8 i am using filters and it is working fine but when i compress my css it stop working.
Here is normal css:

```
.lt-ie9 .myimage:hover{
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#dddddd,direction=0,strength=1),
          progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#dddddd,direction=45,strength=1),
          progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#dddddd,direction=90,strength=2),
          progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#dddddd,direction=135,strength=3),
          progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#cccccc,direction=180,strength=10),
          progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#dddddd,direction=225,strength=3),
          progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#dddddd,direction=270,strength=2),
          progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#dddddd,direction=315,strength=1);
zoom:1;
background-color:rgb(255, 255, 255);}
```

and here is compressed css:

```
.lt-ie9 .myimage:hover{
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#dddddd,direction=0,strength=1),progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#dddddd,direction=45,strength=1),progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#dddddd,direction=90,strength=2),progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#dddddd,direction=135,strength=3),progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#cccccc,direction=180,strength=10),progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#dddddd,direction=225,strength=3),progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#dddddd,direction=270,strength=2),progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#dddddd,direction=315,strength=1);
zoom:1;
background-color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

can anybody tell me what is the solution and reason behind it

Comment: Try CSS3PIE http://css3pie.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comma gets ignored. You need a whitespace or a newline to paste multiple filters.

progid:xxx progid:yyy / works

progid:xxx, progid:yyy / works

progid:xxx
progid:yyy / works

progid:xxx,progid:yyy / will not work

it will be the correct one

```
.lt-ie9 .image-with-align:hover{background-color:#fff;zoom:1;filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#ddddd9,direction=0,strength=1) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#ddddd9,direction=45,strength=1) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#ddddd9,direction=90,strength=2) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#ddddd9,direction=135,strength=3) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#ccccc9,direction=180,strength=10) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#ddddd9,direction=225,strength=3) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#ddddd9,direction=270,strength=2) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#ddddd9,direction=315,strength=1)}
```